# Set visibility through script. Godot

Tags: game-development, godot

My problem is the following:
I wish to make a sprite visible once a button is pressed, other forums I visited suggested I did `visible = false`, but that didn't work, others said I should use `self.visible = false`, but that didn't work either.
I connected the pressed signal of the button to the sprite but the problem comes when I have to change the visibility.

What should I use that will work?

Comment: "didn't work" is not a great way to describe a problem. Did it cause an error? Did it do nothing? did something unintended happen? - Anyway, when you use `self` it refers to the object where the script is running. If that code is running on the button, it refers to the button, if that code is running on the sprite, it refers to the sprite. You say you connected the signal from the button to the sprite, so I guess `self.visible = false` is running on the sprite script on the method connected to the signal. That SHOULD work. I have too little information to figure out why it didn't.

Comment: @Theraot, well it did pop out an error, it said unexpected identifier, but after restarting the program it did what it was supposed to do, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Either setting the 'visible' property to true/false or using the hide()/show() methods should work. There's no apparent reason for any of them 'not working' aside from that maybe you are calling the methods or setting the properties in the wrong object.

Try again in a minimal test scene: A scene with only one node, with a sprite node as the root, and use any texture (like the default icon.png) on it. Attach a built-in script to the node and on the _ready() function try hiding it with 'hide()' or 'visible = false'

Answer (score 1):

First, attach a script to the button you wish to turn on/off the sprite and get the path to your sprite.
Then, you can connect the signal "pressed" on the node menu of your button
Finally, on the press_signal func you change the visibility.

so you will have something like this

```
#Get the path to your sprite
@onready var YourSprite = $Path/To/YourSprite

#Turn on and off the sprite
func _on_pressed():
    YourSprite.visible = !YourSprite.visible
```

If you have trouble getting the path to your sprite please comment and detail how your nodes set.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried some thing and it worked for me, when I have written `$Node2d.visible = true`